# Rails: Can a Nested STI Inherit Custom Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, single-table-inheritance

I have a resource that inherits its table and controller from its parent. Its parent also has custom routing that I want to pass to it, though I'm not sure how (or if it's even possible). The routes currently look like this:

```
resources :publications do
  resources :editions, :controller => :publications
  collection do
    get :autocomplete, :claim, :current_users_publications, :lightbox, :lookup
    post :review
  end
  member do
    get :audit, :reassign_prompt
    post :approve, :audit_vote
    put :reassign
  end
end
```

With the current setup, the editions model does not have access to custom methods like "audit" or "autocomplete." Is it possible to do something like ":routes => :publications"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out **[Routing Concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns)**

```
# Define the concern
concern :somethingable do
  collection do
    get :autocomplete, :claim, :current_users_publications, :lightbox, :lookup
    post :review
  end
  member do
    get :audit, :reassign_prompt
    post :approve, :audit_vote
    put :reassign
  end
end

# And now your routing
resources :publications, concerns: :somethingable do
  resources :editions, controller: :publications, concerns: :somethingable
end
```

I'm sure you can think of a better term than `:somethingable` to describe the common behavior

**Update**

Because the above is for rails `master` branch, there are a couple alternatives you can utilize

1. There is a **[gem](https://github.com/rails/routing_concerns)** that abstracts this behavior for use in Rails 3.2+
2. Instead of using `concern`, just create a method in your routing file.

   ```
   def somethingable
     collection do
       get :autocomplete, :claim, :current_users_publications, :lightbox, :lookup
       post :review
     end
     member do
       get :audit, :reassign_prompt
       post :approve, :audit_vote
       put :reassign
     end
   end
   ```

   then your routes might look like

   ```
   resources :publications do
     somethingable

     resources :editions, controller: :publications do
       somethingable
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: This isn't working for me, though neither am I using Edge Rails. Perhaps I should look into updating. Either way, it's great to know this is there.

Comment: I hope my update bumps you in the right direction for non-`master` branch rails.